# Using enum in a struct results in "unresolved name" error

Tags: rust

I come from a C programming background and started to learn Rust.

Is it possible to use an `enum` in a struct as in the code snippet below?

```
enum Direction {
    EastDirection,
    WestDirection
}

struct TrafficLight {
    direction: Direction,  // the direction of the traffic light
    time_elapse : i32,  // the counter used for the elpase time
}

let mut tl = TrafficLight {direction:EastDirection, time_elapse:0};
```

When I compile the code, it complains that `EastDirection` is not known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is possible. In Rust `enum` variants (like `EastDirection`) are **not** in the global namespace by default. To create your `TrafficLight` instance, write:

```
let mut t1 = TrafficLight {
    direction: Direction::EastDirection,
    time_elapse: 0,
};
```

Please note that, because variants aren't in the global namespace, you should not repeat the `enum` name within the variants name. So better change it to:

```
enum Direction {
    East,
    West,
}

/* struct TrafficLight */

let mut tl = TrafficLight {
    direction: Direction::East, 
    time_elapse: 0
};
```

Comment: Yep, that fixes it. I need to reread the section for namespaces scopes for enums. Thanks for the answer!